# Add metabox in custom plugin page

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I try to add metabox wordpress in custome page plugin, I do not get anything in the plugin page.

I do wrong?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'wp_init_my_plugin');
function add_metabox(){
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metabox');
};
function wp_init_my_plugin() {
    add_menu_page('Config', 'My Plugin', 'administrator', 'my_plugin', 'add_metabox');
};
function metabox()
{
    add_meta_box('box_id', 'The Title', 'metabox_content', 'my_plugin');
}
function metabox_content()
{
     echo "Where is batman?";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meta boxes can only be added to `post type` admin screens, see the `$post_type` arg for `add_meta_box`:

> The type of Write screen on which to show the edit screen section
>   ('post', 'page', 'dashboard', 'link', 'attachment' or
>   'custom_post_type' where custom_post_type is the custom post type
>   slug)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Comment: If you want "where is batman?" to appear on the plugin page, use your `metabox_content` function as a callback for `add_menu_page`: `add_menu_page('Config', 'My Plugin', 'administrator', 'my_plugin', 'metabox_content');`

Comment: Thank you diggy, this resolve my doubt